# how to use onClick function within a condition or calling it in a function? Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to use my PlayerClick(view v) inside a if condition . but it gives me null Exception. it has to retrieve button id.

```
//Main Code where i wan to call
while (gameLoop > 0){

        while(PlayerClick(null) != 1){

            if( WinnerCheck(currentUser.getSymbolValue()) == 1 || WinnerCheck(currentUser.getSymbolValue()) == 0 ){
                return currentUser;
            }

            if (gameLoop % 2 == 0)
                currentUser = me;
              else
                currentUser = opponent;
        }

        gameLoop--;
    }
```

Function Is here

```
 public int PlayerClick(View v) {

//
switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnone:
                     return -1;
            case R.id.btntwo:
                     return -1;
        }
    return 1;
 }
```

Aim to do this just to pause a while loop while right button is being clicked
im using android:onclick = "PlayerClick" for four buttons in XML

Answer (score 0):

> i want to use my PlayerClick(view v) inside a if condition . but it
>   gives me null Exception.

Because you are passing `null` to `PlayerClick` method.

To get it work you should pass Button view which is pressed by user as parameter in `PlayerClick` method.

Comment: i tried    PlayerClick(this.v); its not usefull though cant think of it anymore

Comment: @SlimHarry: what problem you are getting using `PlayerClick(this.v); ` ?

Comment: **Syntax error** ! i dont know what to pass it as a parameter

Comment: @SlimHarry: Use a Global variable in your class as `private View view;`, by default assign first Button to `view` as `view=yourfirstbutton` and then on Button click change `view` to onClick method parameter as `view=v`. then pass `view` in PlayerClick method

Comment: still its not working it passed the first buttion private view to function not detecting other

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById(android.R.id.yourlayout)` pass this in PlayerClick()

like

`PlayerClick(findViewById(android.R.id.yourlayout))`

Comment: you can get the view by this now please specify your question

Comment: im using android:onclick = "PlayerClick" for four buttons in XML

Answer (score 0):

Do

`button.setOnClickListener(this);`

Let your activity implement `OnClickListener`
And when you get onClick(View v) of activity, do as below

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_nativex:
            PlayerClick(v);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int mPlayerClick;

public void PlayerClick(View v) {

    int viewId = v.getId();    
    if (viewId == R.id.btnone) { mPlayerClick = -1; }
    if (viewId == R.id.btntwo) { mPlayerClick = -1; }
    else mPlayerClick = 1;
}
```

And then.

```
while (gameLoop > 0){

    while(mPlayerClick != 1){
    ...
```

I don't understand what you are trying to do though, so this might be wrong. This way `mPlayerClick` will be set to `1` (and stop your loop) only if the user clicks on some button that is **not** either `btnone` or `btntwo`.

Of course all of your buttons need to call `PlayerClick()` on click.